# Babel not compiling a React component from a create-react-app, just copies the code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

We have a repo, built with create-react-app, and now I have the task to expose one of the components - lets call it `<AccountComponent />` - as a standalone component.

So:

1. I have installed @babel/preset-react and @babel/preset-env.
2. In package.json I've added the two presets under babel -> presets.
3. I've added a new file - src/standalone/index.js - that simply imports AccountComponent and exports it by default.
4. I have one more script in package.json for this compilation: `"standalone": "rm -rf dist && mkdir dist && cross-env NODE_ENV=development babel src/standalone -d dist --copy-files"`.

However, when I run `npm run standalone` - I just get the transpiled/compiled new index.js file to dist/index.js ... but this final output doesn't have all the other components and libraries that the target components is using. Thus - it's unusable.

What am I missing something? ... Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with adding a standalone.webpack.config.js file and then my standalone script became

```
"standalone": "webpack --mode development --config standalone.webpack.config.js",
```

And in this additional webpack config I have configured all I needed:

```
module.exports = {
    output: {
          path: __dirname,
          filename: "dist/index.js",
          libraryTarget: "umd",
    },
    entry: {
        main: './src/standalone'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                // exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/i,
                // exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                // exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: "babel-loader",
            },
        ],
    },
}
```

And for the standalone build I'm using this separate file `src/standalone.js`, while the Create-react-app stuff stays intact.

**Important:** The most important part was the libraryTarget property. Until I set it to `umd` - I was getting empty object when I was importing the library in my final app.

Comment: I had a similar problem with rollup where I was getting an empty object instead of a real React library. When I changed the configuration for output -> format from iife to umd - it got resolved :)